# Запуск скрипта каждые 2 секунды

Tags: php, cron

Повесил задачу на каждую минуту в CRON, чтобы он запускал скрипт с бесконечным циклом и таким образом скрипт выполнялся бы каждые 2 секунды, но работает как-то криво. 5-6 раз проработает и перестаёт.

Как можно ещё запускать скрипт каждые 2 секунды или что я сделал не так?

```
  set_time_limit(0);

  while(true) {
   sleep(2);

   $q = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `result_amount`, FROM `lots`");

   while($d = $db->assoc($q)) {
    $id = $d['id'];
    $result_amount = $d['result_amount'];
    $last_bet_user_id = $d['last_bet_user_id'];

    $db->update('lots', array('finish_time' => $time + $config['add_lot_time')), array('id' => $id)); 
   }
  }
```

Comment: так как в целом база/сеть/неведом что может не работать, то скрипт, который хочет долго работать, должен проверять, что ничего плохого не случилось. То есть, должна быть хотя бы элементарная обработка исключений. Но я ее не вижу.

ИМХО, php - далеко не самый лучший язык для этой задачи. Его парафия - быстро отработал, отдал и в забытье.

Comment: и каждую минуту запускается *ещё один* процесс с бесконечным циклом… боюсь, через несколько минут либо ваша система «ляжет», либо эти процессы начнут «падать» с различными ошибками.

Comment: @KoVadim, в какое место исключение нужно?

Comment: @alexander barakin, :(. Какие есть варианты?

Comment: @ModaL, вам толсто намекают, что не должно быть запущено N экземпляров вашего неубиваемого скрипта. Варианты через И/ИЛИ: 1. должно быть условие выхода из бесконечного цикла. 2. на старте надо проверять некий "флажек", что скрипт уже работает. например попытаться поставить [лок](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) в базе. см.

Comment: ModaL, вам правильно подсказывает @artoodetoo . дополню только, что логичнее просто проверять наличие/отсутствие процесса, выполняющего ваш скрипт.

Comment: Или - никакого бесконечного цикла внутри, а запускать так:

`#!/bin/sh 
while(true) do
./script.php; sleep 2
done`

Comment: @klopp, спасибо огромное, запустил bash скрипт и всё работает как нужно. Но только как добавить чтобы скрипт выполнялся даже если закрыта консоль? Превратите комментарий в ответ.

Comment: Разобрался с автозагрузкой. Жду превращения комментария в ответ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты:

1) Написать отдельный долгоживущий скрипт (например на баш) который запустить в screen и пусть он каждый 2 секунды дергает ваш php. Что-то вроде

```
while true; do
  php -f /.../script.php
  sleep 2
done
```

Правда этот будет дергать скрипт с паузами в 2 секунды, а не ровно каждый 2 секунды. В большинстве случаев это хорошо. Так же он не проверяет случай зависания script.php - и если тот повиснет, то выполнение задач остановится

2) В крон создать кучу ежеминутных заданий вида:

```
* * * * * sleep 0.016; php -f /.../script.php
* * * * * sleep 0.032; php -f /.../script.php
```

Первый вариант мне видится более хорошим, если туда обработку зависаний добавить и стартовать процесс например через `systemd` - чтобы он сам тоже не умирал.

Comment: а как предотвратить зависание? А то у меня он всю ночь и до 11 утра проработал и остановился :D

Comment: Внешний скрипт на баше может помереть только если его прибить снаружи (через kill или сервер прибивает по нехватке памяти или закрылась сессия в которой скрипт выполнялся). Если речь о детекте зависания внутреннего скрипта - тут сложнее, я бы написал программку на python/go которая запускает каждые 2 секунды нужный скрипт, а во втором процессе - проверяет насколько долго скрипт выполняется с последнего запуска. Если долго - чтобы прибивал сам. Внешний скрипт попробуйте запускать войдя сначала в screen -RD

Comment: проблема решилась как я стал запускать php-скрипт не через wget.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте триггер в БД и избавитесь от крон задачи со скриптом. В контексте вашего примера это реализуемо.