# Запустить повторяющийся скрипт при включении

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Как запустить при включении компьютера скрипт, который повторяет одну и ту же команду каждые N секунд?

Comment: Интервал кратен минуте? если интервал в минутах то используйте `cron` если меньше, или не кратен минуте, то надо делать свою службу которая будет запускать скрипт с нужными вам интервалами

Answer (score 2):

Используйте штатный планировщик [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) , читайте в консоли по [man crontab](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=crontab&category=1&russian=2)

Comment: А если потребуется частота меньше минуты?

Comment: Да запустите его на фоне в вечном цикле, пусть сам интервал отслеживает и просыпается когда надо.

Comment: @cheops вот здесь есть ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds

Comment: @perefect, ну если ничего лучше нет, можно и так, хотя точность будет - плюс минус лапоть (точнее несколько секунд).

Comment: @cheops там используется нативная функция `sleep` и разницы нет куда ее пихать в крон или в скрипт. а лапоть и так будет все зависит от отклика исполняемого бинарника и загруженности системы.

Comment: @perfect, разница есть: в скрипте `sleep` может быть вынесена каким-нибудь сигналом, в кроне - нет. Поэтому в скрипте чуть сложней. Но зато гибче: можно, например, не выполнять действия, если очередные N секунд прошлёпали, и т.д. В общем, вариантов есть :)

Answer (score 0):

если `n` равно, к примеру, 10 секундам, то можно создать, например, шесть *cron-задач* (выполняющихся каждую минуту — это минимальный промежуток, поддерживаемый популярными реализациями программы *crond*), вторая из которых выполняется с задержкой 10 секунд, третья — 20, и т.д.:

```
* * * * * /путь/к/скрипту/или/программе опции параметры
* * * * * sleep 10; /путь/к/скрипту/или/программе опции параметры
* * * * * sleep 20; /путь/к/скрипту/или/программе опции параметры
...
```

---

другие способы:

- на *ru.so*:

  - [Запуск скрипта каждые 2 секунды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427659/178576)
  - [Как выполнять скрипт чаще 1-ой минуты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808605/178576)
- на других сайтах *so*:

  - [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9619362/4827341)
  - [How to run Cronjobs more often than once per minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4672383/4827341)
  - [How to get a unix script to run every 15 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034243/4827341)
  - [How to run scripts every 5 seconds using cron?](https://askubuntu.com/q/800/416190)
  - [Cron running job every 15 seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11102/110559)
  - [How can I schedule a cron job that runs every 10 seconds in linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/246044/292034)
  - [Can I run a cron job more frequently than every minute?](https://serverfault.com/q/49082/292034)
  - ...

Answer (score 0):

для Ubuntu 15.04 и старше можно использовать systemd/Timers