# Как выполнять скрипт чаще 1-ой минуты?

Tags: php, cron, crontab

Через Cron пускаю скрипт каждую минуту(чаще нельзя, сами знаете). Как можно ускорить этот процесс? Скрипт выполняется на хостинге, там я могу только выбрать тайминг и всё.

Comment: Почему нельзя каждую минуту?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запустить повторяющийся скрипт при включении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543427/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Может тогда стоит задуматься об этом вопросе со стороны самого скрипта, например в PHP есть sleep, можно просто в цикле делать задержку, при этом скрипту разрешить работать без клиента и тогда не прийдется его вызывать через CLI. Надо будет разве что сервер настроить. Вам надо уточнить что у вас за задача?

Comment: Вот по поводу "работать без клиента" интересно, но каким образом я настрою сервер? :)

Comment: Не имею понятия, я же не знаю какой у вас сервер. Но работать без клиента можно и по команде `user_ignore();`

Answer (score 0):

Запускаем задачу раз в 30 секунд

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/mybin/script.sh; /bin/sleep 30; /home/mybin/script.sh
```

Запускаем задачу раз в 20 секунд

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/mybin/script.sh; /bin/sleep 20; /home/mybin/script.sh; /bin/sleep 20; /home/mybin/script.sh
```

Запускаем задачу раз в 15 секунд

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/mybin/script.sh; /bin/sleep 15; /home/mybin/script.sh; /bin/sleep 15; /home/mybin/script.sh; /bin/sleep 15; /home/mybin/script.sh
```

Comment: Ах вы ж хитроумный сударь) Только вот если script.sh будет выполняться не мгновенно, то задержка будет выходить чуть дольше 30/20/15 секунд

Comment: @andreymal, все зависит от скрипта, если гонки состояний не возникнет, то проблемы не вижу. Он жеж отдельным процессом стартанет вроде.