# CRON запуск каждые 10 секунд

Tags: php, cron

Нужно запускать крон каждые 10 секунд. Ответ нашел только в том,что бы сделать 5 экземпляров задачи и слип на 10,20,30,40 и 50 сек соответственно. Но проблема в том,что не могу слип в кроне сделать. Подскажите как.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно и в одном экземпляре. Команды wget и sleep 10 разделять точкой с запятой «;».

Comment: Можете отредактировать запрос как нужно ? Был бы очень рад /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null /bin/sleep 30 site.ru/worker.php?3 Вариант /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null site.ru/worker.php?3 работает исправно @de_frag

Comment: wget ; sleep 10; wget; sleep 10; и т.д. Ну думаю смысл понятен.

Comment: @de_frag 
Я в кроне слаб. Не понимаю толком где что как отделять. Был бы рад примеру. ПыСы. Точки с запятыми ставил везде,разные комбинации,не работает как нужно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск скрипта каждые 2 секунды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427659/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b5-2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Answer (score 9):

Вы можете делать даже так:

```
watch --interval=10 path_to_script.sh
```

Возникает проблема слежения за этим процессом и т.д. Мне хотелось бы все же показать вам один из путей, который намного проще, чем-то с чем вы решили связаться.

**Cron** сам по себе не очень подходит для данной задачи, потому что мы знаем что минимальный интервал работы составляет 1 минуту, но на этом минусы крона для вашей задачи не закачиваются, если ваш воркер начнет задумываться, это создаст лавинный эффект процессов, что в один момент без должной блокировки на уровне скрипта вызовет повышенное использование ресурсов и создаст непредсказуемые результаты, особенно если воркер работает с базой.

Я бы рекомендовал вам для вашей задачи **SystemD** (*если конечно он у вас стоит или есть возможность установить*), и скажу почему:

1. Возможность указывать любой интервал времени, хоть каждую секунду
2. Записывает вывода скрипта в свой журнал и возможность это все посмотреть
3. Можно посмотреть статус задачи systemctl status your-service
4. Можно посмотреть дату последнего запуска и планируемого запуска systemctl list-timers
5. Можно ограничить ресурсы и количество одновременных процессов, по умолчанию будет всегда работать один

Да, конечно есть минусы, **придется создать 2 файла**, в одном указать команду для запуска сервиса и сделать краткое его описание, а в другом (.timer) указать время запуска, против crontab -e с прописыванием команды в редакторе.

**Создаем два файла:**

```
# /etc/systemd/system/project-worker.service

[Unit]
Description=Runs worker
Wants=project-worker.timer

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /path_to_worker_from_root.php

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


# /etc/systemd/system/project-worker.timer

[Unit]
Description=Run project-worker every 10 seconds
Requires=project-worker.service

[Timer]
Unit=project-worker.service
OnCalendar=*:*:0/10

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**Выполняем запуск:**

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable project-worker.timer
systemctl start project-worker.timer
```

**Проверяем статус:**

```
systemctl status project-worker.timer
```

**Полезные команды**

```
systemctl start SERVICE #запуск СЕРВИСА
systemctl stop SERVICE #остановка СЕРВИСА
systemctl status SERVICE #статус СЕРВИСА

systemctl list-timers  # статус всех таймеров

journalctl  # просмотр всех логов less
journalctl -u SERVICE  # просмотр логов сервиса
journalctl -f  # tail всех логов
journalctl -f -u SERVICE  # tail логов специфичного СЕРВИСА
```

Это далеко не полная информация о настройке через SystemD, очень подробное описание есть вот [тут](http://linux-notes.org/pishem-systemd-unit-fajl/).

Конечно, есть еще вариант, что вы можете переписать своего демона и сделать его запуск каждые 10 секунд на уровне программного кода, а SystemD настроить так, что он будет следить за его состоянием, и если он "упадет", то зафиксирует это и перезапустит его.

Решение в целом зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ссылку, давно искал почитать про systemd подробно и на русском.

Comment: Подскажите что должно быть в OnCalendar что-бы запускалось раз в час

Answer (score 2):

А кто мешает сделать скрипт со `sleep` зациклить необходимые действия в нем через `while :;do;done` и прописать этот скрипт в cron с опцией `@reboot`

Скрипт /usr/local/bin/w10

```
#!/bin/bash
while:;do
    wget -O /dev/null bot-nat.tk/worker.php?3
    sleep 10
done
```

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/w10`

И если хотите запуск при старте то в *crontab* запись

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/w10
```

Или так:

```
* * * * * sleep 10;wget -O /dev/null bot-nat.tk/worker.php?3
```

Но так это будет запускать с задержкой в 10 сек. каждую минуту

Comment: Похожий вариант находил. Не осилю такое. Просто не смогу сделать. Самый простой и осиливаемый вариант - с задержкой в в кроне

Comment: А в чем сложность? Могу пошагово прописать. Если есть доступ к root (sudo) то вполне выполнимо

Comment: Как минимум не имею доступа к папке usr ,как максимум - совсем не изучал баш и т.д. . Совсем дико это все и придется потратить н-ное коллво времени на изучение и сделать ваш вариант

Comment: Ну можно тогда из своего cron'a запускать. Если нет возможности устанавливать права на запуск, можно запустить так: `bash имя_скрипта`

Comment: Вариант с кроном мне больше подходит,но я все еще не решил проблему.  Не работает задержка никак. ispmanager

Comment: Пропишите `sleep` перед `wget` [В от здесь у чела заработало](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420799/how-to-sleep-10-seconds-before-running-a-linux-command)

Comment: ++. Реально так пашет. А вгет а потом лип - нет.Спасибо .

Comment: @Danemark если вас устроил ответ и проблема решена, поставьте соответствующую галочку, чтобы другие участники знали что вопрос решен. А то вам больше помогать не будут :)

Comment: Хотя конечная цель действа не очень понятна, наверняка существует более простое и элегантное решение. К примеру зачем делать вывод в stdout и сбрасывать его в /dev/null?

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно делаю так:

```
*/10 * * * * echo "Прошло пять минут"
```

Comment: Это на каждые 10 минут