# Cron чаще чем 1 минута

Tags: php, cron

Есть хостинг с Cpanel, есть ли возможность поставить выполнение php скриптов чаще чем 1 минута?

Comment: Ну вообще есть способы запускать каждые несколько секунд, но это скорей костыли ¯|_(ツ)_/¯ .  Возможно дело не в кроне а в вашей логике приложения? возможно её стоит поменять...

Comment: @Manitikyl всмысле дело не в кроне? Скрипт можно запускать хоть каждые 5 секунд, просто пока не знаю как это реализовать. Или что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @Ayurpwnz он имеет в виду, что скорее вам *не нужно* запускать скрипт «хоть каждые 5 секунд», просто вы, возможно, выбрали неправильное решение своей задачи — то есть [пытаетесь забивать гвозди микроскопом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709). Забить можно, конечно, но нужно ли?

Comment: @andreymal суть скрипта такова: в нем прописана функция, которая создает определенное кол-во ордеров на продажу и покупку, так вот мне нужно чтобы ордера создавались как можно чаще

Comment: @Ayurpwnz для этого совершенно не нужен крон, можно просто запустить скрипт один раз и прописать внутри него вечный цикл, чтобы он работал бесконечно. Ну а задержку в 5 секунд уже вставить внутрь цикла по желанию если нужно

Comment: @andreymal спасибо.

Comment: @andreymal а можно же как-то проверить запущен скрипт или нет? И если запущен, то не выполнять его еще раз

Comment: @Ayurpwnz нормальные системы инициализации и контроля вроде systemd и supervisor умеют следить за своими службами и автоматически перезапускать их

Comment: @Ayurpwnz если вдруг вы по-прежнему пытаетесь забивать гвозди микроскопом, используете обычный веб-хостинг не по назначению и как следствие не имеете доступа к systemd/supervisor и аналогам, то скрипт может записывать свой PID в текстовый файлик, а уже кроном раз в минуту проверять, что процесс с этим PID ещё существует; если перестал существовать, то запускать скрипт заново

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [CRON запуск каждые 10 секунд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851280/cron-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b5-10-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4)